# Codeigniter Failing on Object Property Named 'State'

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an array of objects to loop through, and one public property keeps causing a notice error for CodeIgniter. From what I read, 'state' is not a reserved word in PHP. Part of the object dump

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[15]
      public 'ID' => int 107292435 (length=9)
      public 'RegTypeID' => int 1172891 (length=7)
      public 'StatusID' => int 2 (length=2)
      public 'City' => string 'Philadelphia' (length=7)
      public 'State' => string 'PA' (length=2)
  ...
```

When I loop over each object to output, as seen below

```
foreach ($attendees as $attendee):
    echo "<tr><td>{$attendee->Title}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$attendee->Company}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$attendee->State}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$attendee->Country}</td></tr>\n";
endforeach;
```

**Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$State**

I tried to output using the index value `$attendee->{'4'}` but that failed as well. I would like to avoid looping through and adding another property name to replace this one if possible.

**Adding a print_r result for example:**

```
stdClass Object

    (
        [ID] => 108279742
        [EventID] => 2148055
        [FirstName] => Bob
        [LastName] => Smith
        [Company] => AbbVie
        [Title] => Sample Title
        [State] => IL
        [Country] => United States
    )
```

Comment: No problems with other variables e.g. `StatusID` or `City`?

Comment: Show the model function

Comment: @Alex , no issues on any other variables.

Comment: Weird stuff. You wouldn't happen to have db caching set to on having changed/added this field to the db after the cache was generated? And just to be clear, if you `print_r($attendees);` before the foreach `State` is in there?

Comment: Emm ... where is a repeatable example  from https://3v4l.org ? Because, as I see it, the code works as expected: https://3v4l.org/ESSrv

Comment: @AngrySpartan in your `foreach` add `print_r($attendee);die;` and post the output

Comment: More details needed, please share the print_r output under foreach loop.

Comment: Added an example above

Comment: Check the full dump of `$attendees` and make sure that all entries have the `State` attribute.

Comment: It turns out not all of the records have the 'State' property. Geez, I feel stupid.  Now I have to do a property check.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: You shouldn't feel stupid. We all make mistakes every day. The objective here is to learn and avoid make the same mistake multiple times. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don"t have `State` attribute in all records.

What you can do is to fill before or use an if statement to check and output some default info, like this:

```
echo "<td>". (isset($attendee->State)? $attendee->State : "no info available"). "</td>\n"
```

Comment: You were correct! I actually used `if( property_exists($attendee, 'State')):` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My environment is php 7.1 and codeigniter 3.1.8

I created below function in my test controller for testing purposes and State has output without error message.

```
public function func(){

    $attendee=new stdClass;
    $attendee->ID=107292435;
    $attendee->RegTypeID=1172891;
    $attendee->StatusID=2;
    $attendee->Title='Michael Jackson';
    $attendee->Company='Worlds Best Music Stars';
    $attendee->City='Philadelphia';
    $attendee->State='PA';
    $attendee->Country='USA';

    $attendees=array();
    $attendees[]=$attendee;

    foreach ($attendees as $attendee){
        echo "<tr><td>{$attendee->Title}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$attendee->Company}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$attendee->State}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$attendee->Country}</td></tr>\n";
    }
}
```

Output is like below:

```
<tr><td>Michael Jackson</td>
<td>Worlds Best Music Stars</td>
<td>PA</td>
<td>USA</td></tr>
```